# Some Optimistic responses are not causing the page to re-render? (Apollo and GraphQL with React)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

When deleting an item the page will update immediately with the expected result, but when editing one it will not update until the actual mutation is successful.

I am creating a simple workout tracking app with a friend using the MERN stack. I am using GraphQL and Apollo to query and mutate a mongoDB. Currently we are trying to get the application to be responsive even when the internet connection is poor. I have read that a good way to accomplish this is using the optimistic Response option when firing a mutation. I was able to get it working like a charm when deleting workouts and exercises, but when editing wither of those two the page will not actually update until the mutation has actually resolved. What is odd to me is that it appears the optimisticResponse is working, as I included a console log in the actual resolver and see that it is appearing in the console twice as opposed to just once when the mutation resolves.

Here is the one working as intended

```
async function handleDeleteWorkout(workoutId) {
        setSelectedWorkoutIndex("none");
        try {

            let optimisticWorkouts = [...user.workouts];
            let workoutIndexToReplace = optimisticWorkouts.findIndex(workout => workout._id.toString() === workoutId);
            optimisticWorkouts.splice(workoutIndexToReplace,1);

            const mutationResponse = await deleteWorkout({
                variables: {
                    workoutId: workoutId,
                },
                optimisticResponse: {
                    deleteWorkout: {
                        username: user.username,
                        workouts: optimisticWorkouts
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

and here is the function that handles editing the workout's title which is not updating the page quickly when the connection is poor

```
async function handleWorkoutFormSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        try {
            let optimisticWorkouts = [...user.workouts];
            optimisticWorkouts[selectedWorkoutIndex] = {...optimisticWorkouts[selectedWorkoutIndex], name:workoutEditState.workoutName}
            
            const mutationResponse = await editWorkout({
                variables: {
                    workoutId: user.workouts[selectedWorkoutIndex]._id,
                    name: workoutEditState.workoutName,
                },
                optimisticResponse: {
                    editWorkout: {
                        id: -1,
                        __typename: 'User',
                        username: user.username,
                        workouts: optimisticWorkouts
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        setCurrentlyEditing('none');
    }
```

If anyone has any insight I would really appreciate it. I am still a bit new to all of this, and I think I could have structured my data a bit better in the first place. If I have done something really stupid and obvious here I apologize.

Thank you so much for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a bit foolish for not realizing this sooner, but the issue was that I was using async/await which caused `setCurrentlyEditing('none')`, which toggled what was visible on my page, to not execute until after the mutation was complete.